# Why Typescript allows null/undefined in function

Tags: typescript

Why Typescript allows to pass `null` / `undefined` there?

```
// "strictNullChecks": false
function someFun(param: (foo: any) => any) {}
someFun(null); // no error - incorrect
someFun(undefined); // no error - incorrect
```

Comment: It allows it because, as you know, you have `--strictNullChecks` disabled.  Are you asking "why does disabling `--strictNullChecks` disable strict null checks"?  That's answered below.  Or are you asking "why is `--strictNullChecks` disabled by default"?  That's probably answered [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33634): it would break existing real world code that used TypeScript before these `--strict` options existed.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks)

> In strict null checking mode, the null and undefined values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves **and any** (the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to void)
>
> ..T and T | undefined are considered synonymous in regular type checking mode (because undefined is considered a subtype of any T),